# window.open and $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, popupwindow

I am trying to make a bookmarklet that opens a popup window. Inside this window is a list of CSS classes that once selected, highlights that object on `window.opener` page. So I'm running into two problems.

1. Firebug doesn't work in the popup window, so I can't see what's going on.
2. The window never finishes loading (at least I can tell in Firefox) so the `$(document).ready(function(){...})` inside the window never gets executed.

I can't open the popup from a remote location because I run into cross domain issues. Here is some sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makepopup(){
 var popup = '<!DOC'+'TYPE HT'+'ML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HT'+'ML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">' +
 '<ht'+'ml><he'+'ad><title>Test</title>' +
 '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>' +
 '</he'+'ad><bo'+'dy>' +
 '<div id="wrap">' +
  'testing popup' +
 '</div>' +
 '<input type="button" value="Click Me" />' +
 '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">' + 
 '$(document).ready(function(){' +
 '$(":input").click(function(){ alert($(window.opener.doc'+'ument).find("#test").html()) });' +
 '})' +
 '</scr'+'ipt>' +
 '</bo'+'dy></ht'+'ml>';
 var testpopup = window.open( '','test','toolbar=1,location=0,status=0,width=500,height=450,scrollbars=1' );
 testpopup.document.write(popup);
 return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:makepopup()">Open popup</a>

<div id="test" style="display:none">This is hidden text</div>
```

If I add the following to the console in the popup `$(":input").click(function(){ alert($(window.opener.document).find("#test").html()) });`, it works fine, so I'm sure it the document.ready never being called

Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the `$(document).ready` fire if you add the following line before the `return false`?

```
testpopup.document.close();
```

This is a wild guess though, and I haven't tested this.

Comment: Yes thank you, this does work... do you know of any way to look at the contents of the popup with Firebug?

Comment: @fudgey You can press F12 to open Firebug (a little bit late hahaha)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the `document.ready` never fires.. (*i don't know why ..*)

But you can add your script after the html and remove the `document.ready` since the document is always loaded at that time ..

```
function makepopup(){
 var popup = '<!DOC'+'TYPE HT'+'ML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HT'+'ML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">' +
 '<ht'+'ml><he'+'ad><title>Test</title>' +
 '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>' +
 '</he'+'ad><bo'+'dy>' +
 '<div id="wrap">' +
  'testing popup' +
 '</div>' +
 '<input type="button" value="Click Me" />'  +
 '</bo'+'dy></ht'+'ml>'+
 '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">' + 
 '$(":input").click(function(){ alert($(window.opener.doc'+'ument).find("#test").html()) });' +
 '</scr'+'ipt>';
 var testpopup = window.open( '','test','toolbar=1,location=0,status=0,width=500,height=450,scrollbars=1' );
 testpopup.document.write(popup);
 return false;
}​
```

This works ..

***[UPDATE]***
BUt the method from Aistina is the correct way to go.