# jQuery not working in child window?

Tags: jquery, window, cross-window-scripting

When I write:

```
var x = window.open('','','width=480,height=500');
x.document.write('
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chat.css" / >
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"><' +'/script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hi");
<' + '/script>
</head>
<body><p>hi</p></body>
</html>');
```

I get the alert.

But if I do--

```
 x.document.write('
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chat.css" / >
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
<' +'/script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
alert("hi");
});
<' + '/script>
</head>
<body><p>hi</p></body>
</html>');
```

Then it doesn't work. It does nothing. I've been trying to figure this out all night. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because jQuery never fires the DOM ready event unless you properly `.close()` the document after writing into it:

```
var x = window.open('','','width=480,height=500'),
x.document.write('all your html and script here');
x.document.close();
```

Due credit: [window.open and $(document).ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226163/window-open-and-document-ready)

Comment: OH, jk. By the way, I only formatted it that way for readability-- it's not actually written that way.

Comment: Don't change code when you post. In any case, I tried that code inside jsfiddle and it works okay.

Comment: @Aerovistae Updated answer with fiddle link

Comment: Well, if I didn't separate out the lines then you'd have had a hell of a time reading it. At any rate, as noted above, the line separation isn't the problem-- my actual code just has it in one large block. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Aerovistae I see, have you checked out the Fiddle?

Comment: It's a nice fiddle to be sure, but it doesn't really use jQuery inside the child window, so.

Comment: DAMN That's interesting. Never seen any reference to that bit of info. How'd you figure that out?