# firefox not firing $(document).ready( function() when window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, window.open

I am trying to create a new window dynamically using window.open() and $(document).ready( function() { ... }); I got it working on Chrome and Internet Explorer but firefox is not trigering the jQuery code. See code below:

index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "showDetails('name', 'name2');">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDetails(name, timeStamp)
    {
        var w = window.open("", timeStamp); 

        var s = w.document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "var eventArray = [];";
        w.document.body.appendChild(s);

        var s = w.document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
        w.document.body.appendChild(s);

        var s = w.document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "test.js";
        w.document.body.appendChild(s);

        w.document.title = name;
        w.document.close();
        return false;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

test.js code:

```
alert("executing js file");
$(document).ready( function() 
{
alert("document ready fired");
});
```

The first alert "executing js file" is executing but not the second one "document ready fired".

Any idea how can I make this work on firefox?

**NOTE:**

- **w.document.close(); and return false; is added following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226163/window-open-and-document-ready) but still not working...**
- **jquery is loading properly**

thank you very much in advance

Comment: fiddle here.. http://jsfiddle.net/86KPD/  both alert showing up. Firefox 28!

Comment: make sure you have loaded jquery properly. and check in console for errors like "$ is not defined"

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Hi all, jquery is loading properly and the fiddler works but it is not opening a new window which is the purpose of my question.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to manipulate the DOM properties after opening the window. If that is, in fact, what you're trying to do, it won't work. You can't operate on one document from another.

Comment: Hi marck8, if you are right then why is my code working on chrome and iexplorer and not on firefox? thx for your help

Comment: When you say "working", what do you mean? Please explain what is happening in Firefox and Chrome successfully.

Comment: Hi marck, chrome and iexplorer triggers both alerts inside test.js, however firefox only triggers the first alert that says "executing js file". That means firefox is handling the window.open in a different way, you can run the code above on your computer and see what I am talking about. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

My inner sense says:

```
s.src = "jquery1.10.2.js";
```

should be:

```
s.src = "jquery-1.10.2.js";
```

Or any valid url that points to jquery.

Comment: Hi Amit Joki, my jquery is loading properly. The problem is when I try to open a new window

Answer (score 0):

Why you always use same variable names? Could you please try it like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDetails(name, timeStamp) {
    var w = window.open("", timeStamp); 

    var s1 = w.document.createElement("script");
    s1.type = "text/javascript";
    s1.src = "var eventArray = [];";
    w.document.body.appendChild(s1);

    var s2 = w.document.createElement("script");
    s2.type = "text/javascript";
    s2.src = "jquery1.10.2.js";
    w.document.body.appendChild(s2);

    var s3 = w.document.createElement("script");
    s3.type = "text/javascript";
    s3.src = "test.js";
    w.document.body.appendChild(s3);

    w.document.title = name;
    w.document.close();
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi cenk ebret, I tried changing variable names and still did not work